# Launch command lines from PHP without blocking the navigator

Tags: php, shell, asynchronous

**What I need to do** : I need to launch three commands from an index.php file in the navigator in a shell without blocking the navigator on each command but each command need to wait for the previous one to finish to be able to start.

**What I tried** (used the first note from this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)  :

```
$launchGeneration = function ($appName, $id_application) {
            $cmd = "gradlew assembleDebug && cd ../../../api2 && php scriptUpdate.php " . $id_application;
            chdir("../api/tmp/" . $appName . "/");
            if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
                pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
            } 
            else { 
               exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
            }
            exec($cmd);
    };
```

With this method, the navigator won't wait for the commands to finish but the problem is that I also need the first command to be finish before the others can start. The first one will build an application and only then the third one will modify some data in my database to change the status of the compilation from "waiting" to "done". But in this case, the status will be changed to "done" before the end of the build.

At the moment I am working on Windows but in the end, it will be running on a unix system. If it can't be done with Windows I can switch with debian.

Is there any way to launch several commands one by one without blocking the navigator ?

Comment: send an ajax call to this page from another one, and put before your script : `session_write_close(); ignore_user_abort(true); set_time_limit(0);`, this will unlock concurrent access from a user

Comment: You need a proper backend **independent of a web server**. The web server and PHP processes running within it are for answering web requests, as quickly as possible. You do not run any long operations on your web server. For that you have a daemon/job-queue/worker/something that runs in the background and handles the long running tasks.